# Incorrect favicons

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

This is really not very important, but the favicons for the main site ([link](http://cdn.sstatic.net/ebooks/img/favicon.ico)) and for meta ([link](http://cdn.sstatic.net/ebooksmeta/img/favicon.ico)) are currently the same as the [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) favicons, which presumably they shouldn't be, given that there are no "L"s in "Ebooks".

Comment: Wait for our new name: **Ebook Love & Loathing**.

Comment: Was about to report this on main meta.

Comment: It looks like the correct favicons exist in [favicon-sprite16.png](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png) (which is used e.g. when you get a notification from this site, so that the correct logo shows up in your inbox), but not in [favicons-sprite32.png](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite32.png), which might have something to do with this bug.

Comment: Just came over here to ask that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry about that. I've pushed a new favicon out to dev, it should be on live after our next production build.

Comment: The current build on meta is showing as `2013.12.23.1262`, which I assume means it was pushed out on Dec 23 (today). The favicon on meta has been updated to `EB`, but it looks like the favicon on main is still `ELL`.

Comment: @senshin the correct favicon is on CDN, but it was cached. we'll flush the cache soon.

Comment: @senshin server side cache has been cleared, but you may still have to do a hard refresh. http://cdn.sstatic.net/ebooks/img/favicon.ico

Comment: Yup, working now. Thanks.